# Switch Multi UITableViews in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I have a UITableViewController contains two UITableViews appsTableView and gameTableView, first I set :

```
self.tableView = appsTableView;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

then when I click switch page button to do page switch:

```
-(void) switchPage:(id) sender{


    switch([sender selectedSegmentIndex]){
        case 0: 

            gameTableView = self.tableView;
            self.tableView = appsTableView;  // crash here

           [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
            break;
        case 1: 

            appsTableView = self.tableView;
            [self.tableView removeAllSubviews];
            self.tableView.removeFromSuperview;

            self.tableView = gameTableView;    //crash here
            [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

            break;   
        default: sql = nil;
    }

}
```

both appsTableView and gameTableView have been initialed.
How can I do the switch?

Answer (score 0):

How are the two table views created? I would recommend creating instance variables for them, and retain them when necessary.

```
self.gameTableView = ... // gameTableView is a retain property
self.appsTableView = ... // appsTableView is a retain property
```

Then for the switch:

```
self.tableView = gameTableView;
```

I don't think you need to remove the original table view from the super views as the self. syntax should do that for you. I'm not 100% sure about this though, I'll experiment and get back to you.

**Edit:** you should be safe with the direct assignment (no need to remove from super view).

Comment: Thanks Oscar, I tried and worked! But the new problem is: now the view switch good, for example, I click button to switch from appsTableView to gameTalbeView, both of them can scroll, but when I switch back to appsTableView and try to scroll, crash ...

Comment: what error do you get? It sounds like something was not retained and no longer around.